# SOCKET.ON in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, sockets

I am building a chat app using express socket-io and reactjs.
I have problem for sockets listening on client side using 'socket.on' in reactjs code.
Basically I am not clear where/how to use this code. Which part should I write 'socket.on'?

I have tried using it in componentDidUpdate()  and render(), but I don't get expected results. The console.log in socket.on gets logged multiple times.

Like when I place in render():
It seems that whenever the rerender occurs, it remembers, and as soon as socket.on event occurs, it runs(logs) that many number of times showing output in console.

What is correct way to put socket.on in react component?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use react hooks the solution would be to implement the useEffect pattern.

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on('message', fn)
  return () => {
  // do clean up here
   ...
  }
}, [])
```

if you have to stick to class components your best bet is componentDidMount()

```
// first create a reference to socket so you can clean up later. Either this.socket or just socket, which ever you prefer.
const socket = socketClient(whatEverYourEndpointIs);

componentDidMount() {
    socket.on('message', fn)
}
```

Then you would do a clean up in componentWillUnmount

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    // clean up socket here
}
```

Comment: When I put in componentMount(), it doesn't work at all.... Nothing appears in console

Comment: componentMount or componentDidMount? @HSSingh. Im assuming you just typo the function.

Comment: Yeah, I meant componentDidMount()

Comment: Because, it would be called only first time, not again and again, afaik

Comment: Its hard to tell without seeing the code. But socket.on should only be called 1 time because it is a subscription. After being called once it should be ready to listen to incoming messages.

Comment: @HSSingh I think HermitCrab and I assumed you were creating the socket from the import first. I edited the code to reflect that change.

Comment: Finally it is working. I tried your suggestions. I was doing socket=io() thing in didMount(), but now I am doing it in constructor itself. Now it is working in componentMount().                            Thanks to both of you anyway, I learnt few things

Answer (score 0):

Do not put it in componentDidUpdate or render, otherwise it will be called multiple times. You can call it in componentDidMount so that you are ready to display incoming messages

Comment: When I put in componentMount(), it doesn't work at all.... Nothing appears in console

Comment: Are you connecting first? like this: let socket= io.connect('localhost/chat')